# Running code when a model is deleted via cascade/bulk deletion

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table that basically represents uploads, therefore, when an instance of the model representing this table is deleted, I want the file being represented to be deleted from my uploads folder.

The way I've gone about this thus far is basically overriding the delete method, so that, before the model instance is deleted, the file will be as well.

Problem: not only does this not work for cascade deletions, it also doesnt work if I delete a Collection....

I've looked at Events, like Model::deleting, but they suffer from exactly the same problem (namely they're not triggered by cascade deletions or bulk deletions).

I have also considered a SQL trigger, but it doesnt seem like I can delete files from SQL (inform me if I can, I'd love it! I'm using MySQL, btw).

Do I have an option that is classier than just making a separate query and iterating over it deleting the files every time I need to do a bulk deletion/cascade, or is this really it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-events-getting-started

You need to define an event inside your model.

Comment: @DeadlyBacon Try using the latest version, I don't know if that feature exists in old versions.

Comment: Model events aren't triggered because when you are doing bulk updates/deletion you are using the underlying database query builder, not the eloquent one.

Comment: @mdexp yeah I got that impression too... any alternative you recommend over just having to do a separate query and iterating over it to delete the files?